# Show image in news feed like facebook

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I want to show image in my feed list like facebook if I use resize mode 'contains' it show white space before and after the image please tell me any possible way to resize my image to view in proper aspect ration with white spaces around.

Comment: Will suggest you to share part of the code that you're doing, and best with a screenshot of the result. It helps us to visualize and provide better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `resizeMode : stretch` or `resizeMode : cover` it will cover the whole view. Also ensure any padding or margin in your view. If have any padding in your parent view of image, remove and try it.

see this link: [react native image reize modes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image-style-props#image-resize-mode)